# Firebase Cloud function should return custom model class instead of json

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up a cloud function that returns a custom model object instead of JSON object. Here is the code

```
class Person {
    stack: string;
    age: number;
} 


exports.getUserInfo = function (request, response) {

    cors(request, response, () => {
        
       var myObject = {
           somekey: "some value",
            somekey2: 89,
            somekey3: "brown"
        }

        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let options = {
                uri: "www.example.com",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept",
                }
            }
            requesting(
                options, function (error, res) {
                    if (error !== null) {
                        return reject({err: error});
                    }
                    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                        console.log('body:', res.body);
                        return resolve(myObject);//here I am sending jSON object.. But instead I need to send Person model object.
                    }
                });
        }).then(r => {
            response.status(200).json(r);
        });

    })
}
```

How to return the model object? instead of JSON object . Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but have you tried adding a [`toJSON()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) to your model object?

Comment: I also recommend switching to [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [`gaxios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaxios) for your request needs as these are both used by the Firebase SDKs and have promise-based APIs.

Answer (score 0):

try create your object without using "" in parameter name:

```
var myObject = {
    somekey: "some value",
    somekey2: 89,
    somekey3: "brown"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to Person object. Updated my question.